# JS: копирование метода объекта

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, методы

```
function Rectangle(width,height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    let self = this;
    Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function() {
       return this.height * this.width;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'getArea', 
       {
          enumerable:true,
          value: function() {
                     return self.height * self.width;
                 }
       }
    );

// this.getArea = function() {
//   return self.height * self.width;
// }
}

 function fromJSON(proto, json) {
     let inp = JSON.parse(json);
     return Object.assign(Object.create(proto),inp);
}

let o = new Rectangle(33,2);
console.log(o);
console.log(o.getArea());
console.log(fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype,'{"width":10,"height":6}'));
```

[image: Вывод на консоль]

В итоге при копировании объекта я получаю два свойства, но метод не передаётся. Что делать, где я не прав? Где почитать?

Я так понимаю, метод получается наследуемым и поэтому не копируется? Его нужно ручками дублировать?

Comment: В чем смысл задачи? И зачем getArea добавляется в прототип и в свойства класса одновременно?

Comment: @АлексейМатвеев функция fromJSON должна возвращать новый объект, который основывается на прототипе Rectangle и параметры нового объекта берутся из передаваемой строки JSON. Объект возвращается но без желаемой функции getArea()

Comment: @АлексейМатвеев эта функция есть в прототипе нового объекта.

Comment: @АлексейМатвеев а хотелось бы получить ее как метод нового объекта. Ну и что бы fromFSON была универсальной

Comment: _Rectangle.prototype.getArea =_ стоит вынести из конструктора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем коде зачем-то создаются две функции `getArea`, одна для объекта, который создаётся конструктором, а другая для прототипа.

Первый объект создаётся через конструктор, поэтому имеет и свою функцию, и функцию от прототипа (которая не используется из-за перекрытия первой). Второй объект не создавался через конструктор, а скопировали в него только поля ширины и высоты, поэтому имеет функцию через свой прототип. Вот Ваш код с выводом вызываемых функций:

```
function Rectangle(width,height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    let self = this;
    Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function() {
       console.log("getArea proto");
       return this.height * this.width;
    }

    console.log('Ctor');
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'getArea', 
       {
          enumerable:true,
          value: function() {
                     console.log("getArea property");
                     return self.height * self.width;
                 }
       }

  );
}
function fromJSON(proto, json) {
     let inp = JSON.parse(json);
     return Object.assign(Object.create(proto),inp);
}

let o = new Rectangle(35,2);
let p = fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype,'{"width":8,"height":6}');

console.log(o.getArea());
console.log(p.getArea());
```

На выходе имеем подтверждение вышеописанной трактовки:

> - Ctor
> - getArea property
> - 70
> - getArea proto
> - 48

---

#### Метод в прототипе

В качестве улучшения, я бы избавился от дублирующего метода, а описание прототипа перенёс бы за пределы конструктора (нам же незачем пересоздавать метод прототипа при каждом вызове конструктора).

```
function Rectangle(width,height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return this.height * this.width;
};

function fromJSON(proto, json) {
     let inp = JSON.parse(json);
     return Object.assign(Object.create(proto),inp);
}

let o = new Rectangle(35,2);
let p = fromJSON(Rectangle.prototype,'{"width":8,"height":6}');

console.log(o.getArea());
console.log(p.getArea());
```

Вывод по-сути такой же, а магии в коде меньше:

> - 70
> - 48

---

#### Копирование метода объекта, без пртотипа

Можно обойтись и без использования прототипа. Но тогда нужно будет при копировании всегда отталкиваться от какого-то полноценного объекта, который станет аналогом прототипа:

```
function Rectangle(width,height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    this.getArea = function() {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }; 
}

function fromJSON(proto, json) {
     let inp = JSON.parse(json);
     return Object.assign(Object.create(proto),inp);
}

let o = new Rectangle(35, 2);
let p = fromJSON(o, '{"width":8,"height":6}');

console.log(o.getArea());
console.log(p.getArea());
```

Вывод такой же:

> - 70
> - 48

Comment: `let self = this`  не нужен, так как уже нигде не используется

Comment: @Grundy действительно, не заметил, спасибо.